# position: sticky and problem with Edge browser

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I use bootstrap 4 and .sticky-top class for stick div after scrolling.
But the problem is in edge browser hide div and and unvisiable content of div.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <!-- From here hide in edge brower -->
    <div class="sticky-top">
        <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin efficitur nunc a risus consequat, vel accumsan magna fermentum. Donec magna ex, consectetur ut lectus id, pretium porttitor mauris. In diam odio, feugiat nec fringilla vel, viverra vitae turpis. Quisque eu augue euismod eros varius interdum eu sed sem. Duis dui lectus, placerat eget rutrum et, sodales ut velit. Vivamus eu purus elementum, volutpat risus vitae, vehicula lacus. Vivamus tincidunt nibh sem. Fusce at ante risus. Morbi blandit, tortor vel dignissim dictum, massa nunc lobortis nisl, quis sollicitudin odio tellus eu nisi. Duis mollis risus a fringilla pharetra. Mauris iaculis odio euismod odio egestas egestas. Sed bibendum purus lectus, vel sodales ante maximus id. Vivamus nisl nibh, consequat vitae lobortis et, sagittis sed justo. Sed euismod consequat urna, eu eleifend odio rhoncus vitae. Nullam mauris nulla, scelerisque ut magna ac, porttitor venenatis velit. Etiam vulputate, sem vitae blandit molestie, neque ex commodo lorem, eget maximus tortor orci non est.

Nulla hendrerit ex at justo ornare ultrices at congue purus. Sed venenatis luctus enim, id suscipit est condimentum ut. Aliquam a lacus quis turpis elementum condimentum non sed velit. Praesent feugiat viverra dui, non lobortis leo bibendum non. Suspendisse auctor felis ultrices, tempus purus at, ullamcorper lacus. Mauris consequat, turpis a feugiat mattis, lacus velit iaculis neque, sit amet tempor elit neque sed massa. Aliquam ut tincidunt eros. In vulputate elit et nulla pellentesque fringilla. Duis rutrum turpis et pulvinar lobortis. Pellentesque velit nulla, iaculis a eros elementum, lobortis tincidunt lectus. 

Nullam ut quam elementum, feugiat justo quis, consectetur mi. Donec porta lorem non metus lobortis tempor. Nullam ut ex quam. Ut finibus elit non purus finibus dictum. Cras quis quam lacus. Vestibulum odio neque, lacinia ac efficitur id, accumsan ac massa. Vestibulum lacinia eu augue congue elementum. Sed eleifend laoreet tortor, ac scelerisque felis vulputate a. Fusce vehicula tortor nulla, non sodales dui suscipit id. Donec ut orci eros. Pellentesque eros massa, mattis eu turpis vitae, maximus vehicula libero. Phasellus quis libero metus. Aliquam molestie, enim id suscipit dignissim, ligula magna imperdiet turpis, vel eleifend nisi orci non sapien. 
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
   <!-- to here -->
</div>
```

it's no matter work true .sticky-top class in edge just show this content and don't hide it.

Comment: You should really add some relevant code in your question. Please be accurate.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Seems like some code is missing - please try to create [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qts0uwd/)....

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem. Besides, please try to use F12 developer tools to check the HTML elements and CSS style, make sure it doesn't override.

Comment: Wait till ~January 2020 for a brand new Edge release based on Chromium with Blink and V8 engines

Answer (score -2):

**IE11** and **IE10** will render **position:sticky;** as **position:relative;**

Comment: PS: please read the Q title: *"position: sticky and problem with Edge browser"*